# SQL Window function to find days past due

Tags: sql, date, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I want calculate DPD (days past due) from loan list sorted by date. Every past Due date should re-counted. **See example in attach** . How can I calculate "Days past due" column ?

[image: DPD picture attach]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...? Also, it would be far better to provide your data as tabular text rather than as an image.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What is your desired result? For this loan, would the DPD be 4, 6, 0, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
SELECT
t1.LoanNumber, t1.daydate, t1.Status, case 
when status = 'Past Due'
  then datediff(day, 
             (select max(daydate) from table1 t2 
                where t2.loanNumber =t1.loanNumber 
                and t2.daydate<t1.daydate and t2.status<> 'Past Due'
             ),
             daydate)
   else 0 end as [Days Past Due]
from table1 t1
```

You can try it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/39934/5)

Answer (score 0):

I read this as SQL Server for some reason.  The following uses SQL Server conventions for date functions.  Other databases have similar functions but the exact syntax differs.

The key ida -- a cumulative conditional maximum -- doesn't change:

```
select t.*,
       (case when status = 'PastDue'
             then datediff(date,
                           max(case when status <> 'PastDue' then dayDate end) over (partition by loadnumer order by daydate)
             else 0
        end) as daysPastDue
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to count consecutive days of "past due" and reset the counter in between. This is gaps and island problem.

If dates are always increasing by 1 day, as shown in your sample data, then a method is to take the difference between the date and `row_number()` to define the group each record belong to.

You did not tell which database you are using, so here is a method that uses SQL Server's `dateadd()` to do the date computation; databases that do no support that have an equivalent function.

```
select
    loan_number,
    daydate,
    status,
    case when status = 'PastDue' then 
        count(*) over(
            partition by loan_number, status, dateadd(day, -rn, daydate)
            order by daydate
        ) 
        else 0
    end daysPastDue
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by loan_number, status order by daydate) rn
    from mytable t
) t
order by loan_number, daydate
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=95788eff7f116964244401a98c425e1a)**:

```
loan_number | daydate    | status   | daysPastDue
----------: | :--------- | :------- | ----------:
     111111 | 2020-01-01 | Live     |           0
     111111 | 2020-01-02 | Live     |           0
     111111 | 2020-01-03 | PastDue  |           1
     111111 | 2020-01-04 | PastDue  |           2
     111111 | 2020-01-05 | Restruct |           0
     111111 | 2020-01-06 | Restruct |           0
     111111 | 2020-01-07 | Restruct |           0
     111111 | 2020-01-08 | PastDue  |           1
     111111 | 2020-01-09 | PastDue  |           2
     111111 | 2020-01-10 | Closed   |           0
```